# What does Prometheus summary.observe method do?

Tags: javascript, node.js, grafana, prometheus

I'm trying to play with summary metrics and not quiet understand where do I put summary.observe call? Here is prom-client example (you can find on npm):

```js
    const client = require('prom-client');
    const summary = new client.Summary({
      name: 'metric_name',
      help: 'metric_help'
    });
    summary.observe(10);
```

but there is no enough info how to use it.

1. what does observe(10) mean?
2. where do I put that summary.observe(10) call? Just right after summary metric declaration or at the end of function/endpoint call like:

   ```js
   const client = require('prom-client');

   const summary = new client.Summary({
     name: 'metric_name',
     help: 'metric_help'
   });
   summary.observe(10); // do I put it here?

   async myFunc(){
       await this.serviceCall();
       summary.observe(10); // or here?
   }
   ```

Does anybody have a good example/explanation of summary observe?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, let's clarify what an [summary](https://prometheus.io/docs/concepts/metric_types/#summary) is: a summary metric captures individual observations from an event and summarizes them into a number of related metric:

1. a sum of values (aka observations)
2. observation count
3. quantiles

Taking an example: if you are measuring the response time of a service:

- first, you create a summary metrics providing

  - a name and labels (as usual to identify the metric) - ex: `foobar_request_duration_seconds`
  - usually some way to indicate the windows of measurements (number of observation or maximum age of events)
  - a list of quantiles to compute - ex: 0.1, 0.5 (median), 0.75, 0.9
- for each request, you will compute the response time of a request - this is an observation
- you then feed the computed request response time to the summary object
- when Prometheus scrapes you end-point, metrics are computed from the response time measures observed

  - `foobar_request_duration_seconds_sum`: total number of seconds consumed by requests
  - `foobar_request_duration_seconds_count`: number of requests (note you can compute average with sum)
  - `foobar_request_duration_seconds_seconds{quantile="0.1"}`: response time 10% (... same for all configured quantiles)

I hope this should help you understand the [prom-client documentation](https://github.com/siimon/prom-client#summary):

The first example shows how to indicate the quantiles to compute

```
new client.Summary({
  name: 'metric_name',
  help: 'metric_help',
  percentiles: [0.01, 0.1, 0.9, 0.99]
});
```

The second how to limit the window of measurements; here, measure are computed over the last 10 minutes (using 5 buckets - this impacts smoothing of values):

```
new client.Summary({
  name: 'metric_name',
  help: 'metric_help',
  maxAgeSeconds: 600,
  ageBuckets: 5
});
```

Coming back to your question, the `observe()` method should be called on what you are observing.

If you want to measure some data returned by `serviceCall()`, you feed it to the summary

```
number_bytes_exchanged = await this.serviceCall();
summary.observe(number_bytes_exchanged);
```

If you want to measure the time taken by service call

```
const observe_response_time = summary.startTimer();
await this.serviceCall();
observe_response_time();
```

Comment: Thank you Michael, I was just confused what I really need to pass as a parameter into summary.observe(<?????>); What do they really observe here as per prom-client documentation: summary.observe(10); ???

Comment: They are examples on how to use the object: the `summary.observe(10)` indicates which function to call for a value previously computed (size, number, ...) while `end = summary.startTimer(); end()` is syntaxic sugar for `startTime = now() ; summary.observe(now() - startTime)`. But you are right, called like that in the middle of nothing, it doesn't measure anything.